# Import products from Excel file

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and I have a question about products import. I have the xls file with over 9K positions (products) wich I need to import. For each product in this file there are basically sku, name, price and descriprion attributes. I am familiar with the basics of import/export in Magento. I’ve already exported some test products into csv file to get the structure for import csv. This file of course contains much more attributes than the one i need to import. So my obvious question is: how can I create valid import csv from my xls file (not by hand of course)? The only solution I can see right now is to write some php code that will extract data from the xls file, add required attributes from export csv and save it as csv. Are there other solutions to my problem? Sorry if I am asking some obviuos questions. Googled, searched, found nothing.

Comment: You can use phpexcel for custom php code for retrieving data from xls file, http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way is to save excel as simple csv file and use Magmi for import to Magento. http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Yeah, it seems like Magmi is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.